# How to get the user's time zone in the JIRA API?

Tags: rest, jira

I'm working with the JIRA API (without library) and I need to find out the configured time zone of the current user. I see that there is a [library by JIRA that has a method getUserTimeZoneInfo](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/com/atlassian/jira/timezone/TimeZoneService.html#getUserTimeZoneInfo%28com.atlassian.jira.bc.JiraServiceContext%29). What would be the equivalent http call?

I've searched and searched in google... nothing's coming up. I'm hoping it's just my choice of search terms.

Comment: It would be quite interesting to find-out where is this stored in the database. It seems that his not part of the cwd_user_attributes table, not the cwd_user.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [JIRA REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Version+2+Tutorial) you can achieve this simply making the following call:

```
https://YourJiraServerAddress/rest/api/latest/user?username=YourUsername
```

You will find the loaded "timeZone" field in the response message.

and yes, don't forget to authenticate yourself...